# The format specifier %a for printf() in C

Tags: c, printf

I am reading a C language book, it said `%f, %e, %g, %a` were printf conversion specifications used for `float` and `double` data types. Currently I can understand `%f, %e, %g` completely.

When do I need use `%a` to print `float` and `double` type data ?

Can you please show me an example.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The `%a` formatting specifier is new in C99. It prints the floating-point number in hexadecimal form. This is not something you would use to present numbers to users, but it's very handy for under-the-hood/technical use cases.

As an example, this code:

```
printf("pi=%a\n", 3.14);
```

prints:

```
pi=0x1.91eb86p+1
```

The excellent article linked in the comments explains that this should be read "1.91EB86<sub>16</sub> * 2<sup>1</sup>" (that is, the `p` is for `power-of-two` the floating-point number is *raised to*).  In this case, "1.91EB86<sub>16</sub>" is "1.5700000524520874<sub>10</sub>".  Multiply this by the "2<sup>1</sup>", and you get "3.140000104904175<sub>10</sub>".

Note that this also has the useful property of preserving all bits of precision, and presenting them in a robust way. For instance you could use this to serialize floating point numbers as text, and not have to worry about repeating/infinite decimals.

Also note that  [`strtod()`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/strtod/) can convert floating point numbers in hexadecimal form back to actual numbers. Not 100% sure about `sscanf()` and friends, the documentation was not very clear and I've never used that.

Comment: You can read more about hexadecimal floating-point constants here: http://www.exploringbinary.com/hexadecimal-floating-point-constants/ .

Answer (score 8):

As far as an example of why you would want to use the hex representation, you may want to use %a to precisely represent a floating point value being sent to another machine for processing.

We're using this currently for unit testing an embedded controller by sending data from a simulated plant model that is emulating sensors and actuators to the embedded processor via a UART where the embedded processor does it's control processing and returns feedback (again, float represented as %a) back to the plant model to close the loop.

Comment: Just a heads up on embedded system, at least with the Atmel SAME70 %a and %A don't work

Answer (score 2):

> When do I need use %a to print float and double type data ?

In addition to guaranteed exact representation, printing with `%a` is also much *faster*. When you are printing only a few numbers, that is not much of an issue, but if you are forced to format-print many floating-point numbers, this may well speed your work up. Switching to base 10 and handling rounding each take a not-insignificant amount of work.

Caveat: The I/O may take even more time than the formatting of characters, which may eat away at these benefits; and you might, instead, get away with just printing the raw bytes with no formatting.