# %a conversion specifier not recognized

Tags: awk, printf, posix, gawk, mawk

[POSIX Awk](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_13_10) says:

> The printf statement shall produce output based on a notation similar to the
>   File Format Notation used to describe file formats in this volume of
>   POSIX.1-2008 (see XBD File Format Notation).

And [File Format Notation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap05.html) defines `%a`:

> The floating-point number argument representing a floating-point number shall
>   be converted in the style "[-]0xh.hhhhp±d" [...]

However neither Gawk nor Mawk support this:

```
$ gawk 'BEGIN {printf "%a", 1}'
%a

$ mawk 'BEGIN {printf "%a", 1}'
mawk: run time error: improper conversion(number 1) in printf("%a")
```

Why is this?

Comment: Best guess: `based on a notation similar to` != `identical to`.

Comment: If I try with POSIX awk, I get `weird printf conversion %a` Do you get the output you expect under a version of POSIX awk?

Comment: @dawg perhaps I am not being clear: POSIX Awk is Awk as is defined by the standard, not necessarily any one implementation. It appears that no implementation is POSIX compliant with respsect to `%a`, or maybe I am misreading the standard

Comment: According to the Gnu Awk User's Guide:

https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Control-Letters.html#Control-Letters

%a is not a supported format character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking at the POSIX 2008 SUSv4 ([Single Unix Specification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_UNIX_Specification)) documentation. A lot of software pre-dates this, `gawk` included. I suspect the `gawk` implementation is 2001 SUSv2, and has not been updated completely over time.
The Linux (glibc) [`printf(3)` man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) alludes to this problem (see the description of `%a` about half way through, sorry no anchors to link to):

> **a, A**
>
> (C99; not in SUSv2) For a conversion, the double argument is converted to hexadecimal notation (using the letters abcdef) in the style [-]0xh.hhhhp±;  [...]

`nawk`/`mawk`/`gawk` don't simply call the underlying libc's `printf()` or `sprintf()` verbatim, they more or less reimplement format string processing. For `mawk` see the [`do_printf()`](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/22120761/#l-430)
function for example. Perl also implements its own format processing, the [`sprintf` man page](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html) is more up front about the details.

Things which *do* support `%a`/`%A` are:

- glibc-2.1 and later (1997), it's required for [C99 features](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Hex-Floats.html)
- coreutils-5.1(ish) `printf` (i.e. `/usr/bin/printf`)
- bash's builtin `printf`, since bash-2.05 if libc has support
- perl's `sprintf` since perl-5.22.0

See the accepted answer here for some additional background: [The format specifier %a for printf() in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4826842/the-format-specifier-a-for-printf-in-c)